# select on php and call it from html

Tags: php, html

please someone help me, I need this select on php and after just call it from html like this , because if I need add more countries in the future, I just need change the php and not every page.

this is the select.

```
<select name="select_country" onchange="location = this.value" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 120px;">
<option value="">Countries</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Reino Unido</option>
<option value="http://link.com">España</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Francia</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Japón</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Suiza</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Otro</option>
</select>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please Explain in more details. What you want to do?

Comment: Sorry!. I have this code in my page, but I don't want change every page in the future if I need add other option in the select, so I would like have this select in php and put in my pages just <?php include("countrie.php"); ?>, so every time that I modify the php file, in every page appear the change, Is it correct? sorry for my English.

Comment: But I'm not sure, how can I do this select on php

Comment: For this you can use **<?php include_once('countrie.php');?>** add this line where you want to show countries name

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how do I do the php file with the select :(

Comment: Try and paste the following code somewhere in a webpage to see if php can execute in-line on your website... **<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>**

Comment: No, it is not executing, how can I fix it.? thanks a lot

Comment: Some hosts do not have inline php enable on all filetypes... You could ask your host for clarification, or try changing the page extension to .shtml and try again.... Some hosts have it set to work on shtml.

Comment: If PHP is not an option, you could acheive the same using javascript and have the content populated on page load via an external .js file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for this just first create a **select.php** file and put your countries code in their like this:-

**select.php**

```
<select name="select_country" onchange="location = this.value" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 120px;">
<option value="">Countries</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Reino Unido</option>
<option value="http://link.com">España</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Francia</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Japón</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Suiza</option>
<option value="http://link.com">Otro</option>
</select>
```

Now, When you want to add this code in any pages like countries.php then you can easily show this code like this :-

**countries.php**

```
   <body>
/*SOME CODE YOU WANT TO ADD BEFORE LIST OF COUNTRIES */
<?php include_once('select.php');?>
/*SOME MORE CODE*/
.
.
.
.
</body>
```

Try this. So, in future you have to just change the countries in select.php then rest of the page which have  line will be automatically changed.

Comment: Just a note: this answer would work for people who have inline php enabled on the filetype in use.